# Has Stack Overflow appointed people to answer questions?

Tags: discussion, users

I seen from last two years some persons are always available to help on Stack Overflow. It will be great and appreciate it. Because, in personal life we have many works rather than helping on Stack Overflow without minding their personal characteristics. I am just wondering about the following questions with a personal opinion of me and my friends:

1. Are they officially working on Stack Overflow?
2. If not, then what is the use of answering on Stack Overflow?
3. If no, do they do it for money?
4. Does Stack Overflow give any physical badge to them? (If I forgot or lost my email and password it will help me to get back my account.)

Comment: How do you get to 3k rep and not understand this? YOU have answered 75 questions freely. Just like everyone else who answers questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, most answerers are not working for Stack Overflow. There are some developer-evangelists who work for third-party technology companies, but they are the exception. Most people are volunteers, and they do not get paid. When they help, they are usually doing so in their own free time.

People help because they:

- are helpful
- wish to give back to a community that has helped them
- enjoy solving difficult problems
- believe in the site's goal of building a free resource of programming questions and answers
- like to acquire "reputation" points that may help them get a job in the future